# C++ conflicting pointer declaration in h and cpp file

Tags: c++, pointers

So I need a method that takes a Person pointer as it's parameters. This means that I have to declare it in both my header file and my cpp file. It looks like this.

*PersonReg.h*

```
#pragma once
class PersonReg
{
public:
    PersonReg(int const maxSize);
    void addPerson(Person* personPtr);
    ~PersonReg();
};
```

*PersonReg.cpp*

```
PersonReg::PersonReg(int mSize)
{
    maxSize = mSize;
}

void add(Person* personPtr) {
    //Do stuff
}

PersonReg::~PersonReg()
{
}
```

The problem is that Visual Studio complains that the function definition for addPerson is missing and giving the suggestion to implement it. If I do, it looks like this:

```
void PersonReg::addPerson(Person * personPtr)
{
}
```

Now what is happening here? Why can't it find my implementation?  What does spaces around the asterisk mean? What's the difference?

Comment: Because you don't *have* a definition (implementation) of `PersonReg::addPerson`. You *do* have a global non-menber function called `add` though.

Comment: Whitespace is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

```
void PersonReg::addPerson(Person* personPtr) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Is what you need. You've missed out the bit where you say the correct name and namespace of the function.

Also I don't think the spaces around the asterisk matter. Some people leave out the space next to the type, some next to the name.

Comment: I see. Well that fixed that error, but it still says that the params are incompatible. :S Doesn' my header file include my Person.h file aswell?

Comment: For some reason I removed the return type.

Comment: Is "namespace" the proper term for this?  (it means other stuff, too)

Comment: Happen to be reading Stroustrup's c++ book on the train this morning, and he says "Classes are namespaces" in chapter 14.2.1 at the end.

Comment: @brulle3 your cpp file needs to #include the header, but not the other way round. Let me know if it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you made the function `void add(Person* personPtr) {` you have defined a function that is not inside a class and it doesn't have any connection to it. On the other hand when you used the scope resolution operator `::` you have overloaded a function which had the prototype within the class.

To put it simple, doing `void PersonReg::addPerson(Person * personPtr)`
 refers to the function within the class.

If you are doing `void add(Person* personPtr) {` you are defining another function which is not part of the class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: _"you have overloaded a function which had the prototype within the class"_. I don't think using scope resolution operator means _overloading_ the function which we just had prototyped inside the class. It's just the implementation of that prototype.

Comment: Actually it is the both, you can use the scope resolution operator to overload a function and to implement it. But if you are implementing the function using the scope resolution operator I believe it has to be abstract or virtual in c++ which is not actually the case, therefore I say my previous answer was correct. BTW this is not a full documentation on the scope resolution operator. :)

Comment: So, what I'm getting from your comment is: if I have defined a function prototype `void add();` in header file inside `Person`. I can implement its overloads like `void Person::add(int a)` in cpp file without specifying the overload's prototype?

Comment: Or if I give implementation of a function whose prototype have given in the header. It must have to be a virutal or abstract method? Otherwise it would be an error to give the method's body in cpp?

Comment: If you want to implement the function outside the class, you need to define it as pure virtual. If you want to overload the function outside the class, you need to use the scope resolution operator, but i am not sure if this will give you an error or not. I'll have a link to a reference below this comment.

Comment: http://www.studytonight.com/cpp/abstract-class-and-pure-virtual.php and http://www.studytonight.com/cpp/function-overloading.php , unfortunately I haven't found a reference to the both of them but you may try to combine them.

Comment: I don't know whether you have a misunderstanding of the concept or you're just not getting what I'm saying.

Comment: I do understand the concept very well, the issue might be that i haven't understood the question very well.